# Excel: How to take all results of a cell of a range of values in calculations

Tags: excel

Cell A1 result comes from several calculations.

simplified example:

```
A1= B1+C1
B1= D1+1000
C1= E1*F1
```

For any new value in F1 I give a new result in A1.
I want to have all results of A1 for a range of values in F1.

ex: for F1 from 100 to 200, all A1 results write in a column

Comment: Above code is a simplified example. I want to give a range to F1 and take the results of A1 regardless how A1 value is obtained

Answer (score 0):

You can use following formula if you define range in one cell (`F1 = 100:200`):

```
=AGGREGATE(15,4,$D$1+1000+$E$1*ROW(INDIRECT($F$1)),ROW())
```

or if you want define range in separate cells (`F1 = 100`, `F2 = 200`):

```
=AGGREGATE(15,4,$D$1+1000+$E$1*ROW(INDIRECT($F$1&":"&$F$2)),ROW())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to type calculations inside the formula. It is several steps of calculations between A1 and F1 (I gave a simple example above, but originally it is complicated). I want to give a range to F1 and take the results of A1 regardless how A1 value is obtained